# Does using PDO in php use a lot of resources compared to a normal mysql connection?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

Basically I was talking to a friend who critised me for using PDO over mysql methods. His argument is that using

```
$dbh = new PDO(irreleventparams);
```

forces you to get the full class and constants of PDO and hence takes a lot more resources than necessary, as the only methods from PDO I would need to use are `prepare()`, `bindParam()` and `execute()`, as opposed to the mysql methods already contained in PHP.

So my question is this, is this really the case that it needs to import all the constants and methods, and how much of a drawback is this in terms of resources, is it negliable, is it noticable? Bearing in mind the server may be pushed to its limit with requests and so using the least amount of resources is preferable.

Comment: That is balderdash. =) To go a little more in detail — it may or may not, but it doesn’t matter. The use of a class over a set of functions is never going to be your bottleneck, and convenience and security is worth more than a few microseconds of performance gain.

Comment: If you use `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` property, then your page won't have to crate new connections with db, everytime is refreshes/runs/does something.. so, you'll be saving a LOT of resources

Comment: Agree with above, negligible. If you're having resource issues it most certainly won't be the use of `PDO` over `mysqli`...Also, never assume that you'll only be using three functions. You'll most likely end up in situations where you need to utilize much more of the class.

Comment: PDO's prepare(), bindParam() and execute() are "already contained in PHP" as well. And - oh, you are taking performance from totally wrong end.

Comment: Thank you everyone, this gives a lot more clarity. 

Although @YourCommonSense I did not know that, does that mean the server does not have to important PDO every time it creates the object?

Comment: I don't understand your question even with replacing 'important' to 'import'. Nevertheless, as I said, you are taking performance problem from completely wrong end. All these operations like 'import', 'getting class and constants' being quite imaginary to you, yet whatever performance penalty they cause being imaginary as well. Do not optimize imaginary problems. Find a real cause for your code to run slow and optimize this one. That's all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense In java when you import a library it has to download that extra library to be able to use it. This takes up time and resources for the computer. I'm asking if doing this in PHP for PDO is similar, and if so how much slower is it.

Ignoring the rest of the code's efficiency, this is the only part I am concerned with at the moment. If a performance penalty exists, it is not imaginary, so I want to understand the degree of the penalty if any.

Comment: Oh, I see now. No, PHP does not download anything, you have to compile it with all the required libraries first. So, by the time of calling PDO, it is already up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step in addressing a performance complaint is to prepare a benchmark comparing method A with method B. The next step is getting other people to have a look at your benchmark to make sure you're not missing an obvious optimization.

I would rather be using PDO to the fullest extent possible and know my code is safe from SQL injection than to use something dirty and low-level like `mysql_query` and hope that it is. All the performance in the world is pointless if you get stung by a SQL injection bug due to a careless mistake and someone steals your database.

Remember that with a properly configured PHP runtime environment, and using MySQL connection pooling, the differences between different database layers should be minor.

You should compare `mysqli` to PDO and any other database interface you think is worth considering, like [ADOdb](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm) perhaps. Construct tests with queries representative of the work you're trying to do, not just dummy queries like `SELECT 1`. It's best with a real schema loaded down with tons of dummy data, more than the production system might have to deal with, so you can get a sense of how it will perform under load.

If the application server is "pushed to its limit" then you probably need more application servers.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that while the traditional mysql_connect() and related functions are marginally faster, the difference is absolutely negligible.  And even if the difference was a bit more than it is, it would still be worth it in every way to use PDO; it's faster to type and there's less to concern yourself with security-wise.